# Unique Entity Error message

Tags: api, symfony, exception, doctrine

I have a user entity which have some unique fields.

The code bellow shows you how I defined it.

```
/** 
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"login"}, message="UNIQUE ERROR MESSAGE")
 */

 ......

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="login", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $login;
```

Developping an API, I would like to be able to send the right error status with the right error message.

When I insert a duplicate entry in the database, I would like to get the message and an exeption relative to the fact it is a duplicate.
Instead I get a 500 error with the SQL Message.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": [
        {
             "message": "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO  .... \n\nSQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"uniq_1d1c63b3aa08cb10\"\nDETAIL:  Key (login)=(bast) already exists.",
            "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\DBALException",
            "trace": [
```

Here is where I get the 500.

```
    $test = new Utilisateur();
    $test->setLogin('test');

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $manager->persist($test);
    $manager->flush();
```

How can I retrieve the message "UNIQUE ERROR MESSAGE" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Symfony validator service can be used directly to validate any object for which validation constraints are defined. For example in a controller:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($test);
```

To perform validation within a service you can pass the validator service into your service.